# No Persistence provider for EntityManager in RCP Pulgin Project

Tags: jpa, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am getting a

```
No Persistence provider for EntityManager for named X
```

in an RCP Plugin application I am working on. I have used hibernate as ORM and javax.persistence. I am using Derby for my database. I have grouped all the hibernate Jar and supporting jars into a plugin and added to the current project i am woking on. I am at my wits end. Any help would be appreciated. i have as of now looked at different places for answers but not found any.

I have placed the Persistence.xml file in the classpath under/META-INF/persistence.xml. I have tried placing the persistence.xml at these location - **/RCMSecond/src/persistence.xml** and **/RCMSecond/src/META-INF/persistence.xml** and **/RCMSecond/META-INF/persistence.xml** still the RCP project is throwing the same error stacktrace.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="RCMSecond" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>entity.ColumnMeta</class>
    <class>entity.DataBase_CompositeID</class>
    <class>entity.Files</class>
    <class>entity.Database</class>
    <class>entity.LookUpCols</class>
    <class>entity.Project</class>
    <class>entity.QueryEntity</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:simpleDB;create=true" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE" />
      <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="format_sql" value="true"></property>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**GenericDAOImpl.java**

```
package daoImpl;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import dao.GenericDAO;
import exceptions.EntityNotPresent;

public class GenericDAOImpl < T, ID extends Serializable > implements GenericDAO < T, ID > {

  protected EntityManager entityManager;

  protected EntityTransaction entityTransaction;

  public GenericDAOImpl() {
    super();

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RCMSecond");
    this.entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
    entityTransaction = this.entityManager.getTransaction();

  }

  @
  Override
  public T save(T t) {
    entityTransaction.begin();
    entityManager.persist(t);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityTransaction.commit();
    return t;
  }

  @
  SuppressWarnings({
    "unchecked", "rawtypes"
  })@ Override
  public List < T > readAll(String namedQueryName, Class clazz) {
    TypedQuery < T > query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(namedQueryName, clazz);
    return query.getResultList();
  }

  @
  SuppressWarnings("unchecked")@ Override
  public T readById(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz, ID id) {
    entityTransaction.begin();
    T t = (T) entityManager.find(clazz, id);
    entityTransaction.commit();
    return t;
  }

  @
  Override
  public T update(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz, ID id, T updated) throws EntityNotPresent {
    if (isEntityExists(clazz, id)) {
      entityManager.merge(updated);
      return updated;
    } else {
      throw new EntityNotPresent("Entity Not found, So Could not be updated");
    }

  }

  @
  Override
  public void delete(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz, ID removeId) {

    if (isEntityExists(clazz, removeId)) {
      T old = readById(clazz, removeId);
      entityTransaction.begin();
      entityManager.remove(old);
      entityTransaction.commit();
    }
  }

  @
  SuppressWarnings("unchecked")@ Override
  public boolean isEntityExists(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz, ID id) {
    return entityManager.find(clazz, id) != null;
  }

  @
  SuppressWarnings("unchecked")@ Override
  public T getFirstRecord(Class <? > clazz) {
    entityTransaction.begin();
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Criteria queryCriteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
    queryCriteria.setFirstResult(0);
    queryCriteria.setMaxResults(1);
    T t = (T) queryCriteria.list().get(0);
    entityTransaction.commit();
    return t;

  }

  @
  Override
  public List < T > getByQuery(String queryExecute, Object[] pars, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class clazz) {

    entityTransaction.begin();@
    SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    TypedQuery < T > query = entityManager.createQuery(queryExecute, clazz);
    for (int i = 0; i < pars.length; i++) {
      query.setParameter("arg" + i, pars[i]);
    }
    List < T > results = query.getResultList();
    entityTransaction.commit();
    return results;

  }
}
```

**StackTrace**

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider
for EntityManager named RCMSecond
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java: 68)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java: 898)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java: 121)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java: 345)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java: 264)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java: 162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java: 104)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java: 73)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java: 55)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java: 129)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java: 971)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 640)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java: 717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java: 42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java: 1306)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java: 72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java: 40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java: 186)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java: 4761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java: 211)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java: 36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java: 197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java: 197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java: 1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java: 230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java: 148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java: 135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java: 78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java: 39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java: 85)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java: 59)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java: 374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java: 171)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java: 108)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 658)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java: 717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java: 42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java: 71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java: 151)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 654)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java: 717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java: 42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java: 71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java: 49)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 654)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java: 717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java: 42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java: 82)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java: 72)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java: 40)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java: 186)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java: 4761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java: 211)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java: 36)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java: 197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java: 197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java: 1)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java: 230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java: 148)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java: 135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java: 78)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java: 39)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java: 85)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java: 59)
at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java: 374)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java: 135)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PerspectiveStackImpl.setSelectedElement(PerspectiveStackImpl.java: 1)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java: 108)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java: 63)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 658)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java: 717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java: 42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java: 71)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java: 614)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 654)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 746)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java: 717)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 711)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java: 42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java: 695)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 1057)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java: 337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java: 1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java: 156)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.start(E4Application.java: 159)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java: 196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java: 134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java: 104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java: 380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java: 235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java: 669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java: 608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java: 1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java: 1488)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider
for EntityManager named RCMSecond
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java: 61)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java: 39)
at daoImpl.GenericDAOImpl. < init > (GenericDAOImpl.java: 30)
at daoImpl.DatabaseDAOImpl. < init > (DatabaseDAOImpl.java: 14)
at com.view.FirstView.createControls(FirstView.java: 31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java: 56)
  ...112 more
```

I have tried placing the persistence.xml at these location - `/RCMSecond/src/persistence.xml** and **/RCMSecond/src/META-INF/persistence.xml` still the RCP project is throwing the same error stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm

> The JAR file or directory whose META-INF directory contains
>   persistence.xml is called the root of the persistence unit. The scope
>   of the persistence unit is determined by the persistence unit's root.
>
> Persistent units can be packaged as part of a WAR or EJB JAR file or
>   can be packaged as a JAR file that can then be included in an WAR or
>   EAR file.
>
> ```
>  • If you package the persistent unit as a set of classes in an EJB JAR
>    file, persistence.xml should be put in the EJB JAR's META-INF directory.
>
>  • If you package the persistence unit as a set of classes in a WAR file,
>      persistence.xml should be located in the WAR file's 
>    WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory.
>
>  • If you package the persistence unit in a JAR file that will be
>      included in a WAR or EAR file, the JAR file should be located in either 
>          - the WEB-INF/lib directory of a WAR Or 
>          - the EAR file's library directory
> ```

Check configuration. Your Eclipse should be able to map resource files and build all packages. check Project->Properties->Build Path in order to configure project dependencies.

---

*offtopic tips:*
You are trying to obtain the EntityManager by injection:

```
  @PersistenceContext
  protected EntityManager entityManager
```

Then to obtain the EntityManager from the EntityManagerFactory instance:

```
   EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RCMSecond");
   this.entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
```

Comment: Thank You, I will check it and update soon. And also yes, i had not noticed that EntityManagerFactory was being injected twice. The problem is that the Eclipse RCP project has its own ways of resolving the classpath. Not the normal way we do for Java projects. So adding the persistence.xml to the classpath is being difficult.

Comment: I have placed the Persistence.xml file in the classpath under/META-INF/persistence.xml. I have tried placing the persistence.xml at these location - /RCMSecond/src/persistence.xml and /RCMSecond/src/META-INF/persistence.xml and /RCMSecond/META-INF/persistence.xml still the RCP project is throwing the same error stacktrace.